# Theming a React project using Scss and JS variable

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

is there a way to import javascript variables in scss file?
For example, I have this javascript file and want to use it in my scss file.

```
// sky blue
const PRIMARY_COLOR = '#489FEF'    
export { PRIMARY_COLOR}
```

and I want to use it in my scss file as

```
.sampleClassName { border: $PRIMARY_COLOR 3px solid }
```

The reason why I am doing this is that I want to theme my project and style it using SCSS. If there is any better way of doing this, please tell me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [styled components](https://styled-components.com/)

```
const PRIMARY_COLOR = "#489FEF";

const Button = styled.a`
  border: ${PRIMARY_COLOR}
`;
```

I'd not approach a component like this though, and [I'd suggest making themes as shown here](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#theming).

Answer (score 0):

There is a package that parses and converts exported JS values into scss types using node-sass. You would then be able to `require` the js file into your scss like any other scss file. Works with Webpack as well.

[sass-ffi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-ffi)